# foreach return all elements on one var

Tags: php, wordpress, svg, foreach

I need to put all the `$path` variables on `$html`.  When run the code, the first `$path` is on the `$html`, but all other `$path`'s put out the `$html`.

```
<?php 
    $posts = get_posts('cat=4');
    foreach ($posts as $post) {
        $postId = get_the_ID($post);
        $postPrintId = $post->post_name;
        $paths = get_field('path', $postId);
        if($paths) {
            foreach($paths as $path) {
                $cordenadas = $path['cordenadas'];
                $path = '<path d="'.$cordenadas.'"/>';
            }
        }
        $html  = '<g id="'.$postPrintId.'">';
        $html .= $path;
        $html .= '</g>';
        $html .= '';
        echo $html;
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative to the above answer.
Produces the same output, though, some might call it hackish.

So, instead of adding `$html .= $path`, add the following.

```
$html .= implode('', $paths);
```

Then change `$paths as $path` in the for loop to `$paths as &$path`. (Notice the ampersand?)

### Explaination

The implode function takes all variables in an array, and separates them with a string. In this case, the string is `''`.

The ampersand tells PHP to make the variable a reference. This allows us to modify it easily in the array.

Answer (score 2):

You are overwriting `$path` each time in your foreach loop, you need to concatenate that value instead using `.=` and make sure it's cleared *before* the loop to avoid it doubling up next time:

```
$posts = get_posts('cat=4');
foreach ($posts as $post) {
    $postId = get_the_ID($post);
    $postPrintId = $post->post_name;
    $paths = get_field('path', $postId);
    $path = ''; // reset each iteration
    if($paths) {
        foreach($paths as $path_info) {
            $path .= '<path d="' . $path_info['cordenadas'] . '"/>';
            //    ^---- concatenate, not replace!
        }
    }
    $html  = '<g id="'.$postPrintId.'">' . $path . '</g>';
    echo $html;
}
```

As pointed out, you were also using `$path` as your loop variable *and* an external variable containing results.

Comment: Good answer, except, you're trying to overwrite 2 variables. I'd change the `$path` variable that has the HTML, to `$pathResults`. Or something similar.